# Converting decimal input in a Javafx textfield to a double

Tags: java, javafx

So, I'm pretty new to javafx and was trying to use the textfield to take in a string and then, using a try catch, convert the string to a double if possible. The only problem I'm having is that if I enter a decimal, ex 1000.56, the catch activates and my error label pops up saying that it can't take in a string. This is the relevant block of code, please assume I have all the proper imports and all the basic setup for the variables done.

```
            //takes in the users input and trims spaces
            holder[i] = txtFld.getText().trim();
            while(run == false) {
                try {
                    //attempts to parse the stripped text to a double
                    amt[i] = Double.parseDouble(holder[i]);
                    //allows the loop to break
                    run = true;
                }catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                    txtFld.setText("");
                    //tells the user about the error
                    grid.add(Err, 0, 3);
                }
            }
```

Comment: have you printed out the value of `holder[i]` to ensure that what you are passing to `parseDouble` is actually `"1000.56"`?

Comment: Oh jeez; I feel very stupid. I had it so that after that prompt, another one came up using the same text field, and I accidentally put the thing that cleared it at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do loops like this in JavaFX for several reasons:

- A loop like this blocks the application thread. This results in no inputs being processed while the loop is running.
- You modify the text even if the input is not finished. Consider the scenario wher the user wants to input `-1E3`. The only way your code would allow this input would be stepwise changing the text like this: `"" -> "1" -> "-1" -> "-13" -> "-1E3"`

The simplest fix would be to simply check on "submitting" the data. Alternatively listen to the `TextField.text` property and display some indication of invalid input (e.g. some icon) but **do not modify the text on every change**.

There's some implementation already available that tries to parse the text on focus loss: `TextFormatter`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextField textField = new TextField();

    TextFormatter<Double> formatter = new TextFormatter<>(new DoubleStringConverter(), 0d);
    textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);

    formatter.valueProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("value changed to " + newValue));

    Button button = new Button("some other focusable element");

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(textField, button));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

#### Edit

For "submission" buttons simply validate the value from the event handler:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    Label textErrorLabel = new Label();
    textErrorLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);

    HBox textBox = new HBox(10, textField, textErrorLabel);
    textBox.setPrefWidth(300);

    Button button = new Button("Submit");
    button.setOnAction(evt -> {
        boolean valid = true;
        double value = 0;
        try {
            value = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
            textErrorLabel.setText("");
            textField.setStyle(null);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            valid = false;
            textErrorLabel.setText("erroneous input");
            textField.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: red;");
        }

        // you could do more input validation here...

        if (valid) {
            System.out.println("successfully submitted "+ value);
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(textBox, button));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I have the actionEvent based on the user pressing a separate button on the side; I guess I should have mentioned that, sorry.